# Multiplying Base10 and Base2

Tags: binary

When multiplying (or doing any mathematics) to binary and decimal numbers, would you simply convert then multiply in decimals?

E.g., 3(base10) * 100(base2) would = 3 * 4 = 12?

Comment: You're talking about doing this on paper, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can multiply in any base as long as the base is the same for each operand.

In your example, you could have converted the 3(base10) to 11(base2) and multiplied:

11 * 100 = 1100

1100(Base2) = 12(base10)

Comment: but i converted mine to base10 * base10 and got a base 10 answer

Comment: Correct.  Your answer will be in the same base as what you started with.  If you convert everything to binary, your answer will be in binary.  If you convert everything to decimal, your answer will be in decimal.  You'll get the same answer either way, just in a different base.

Comment: awesome. i thought so but wanted to make sure. Ty so much

Comment: Math is awesome like that.  Numbers are just numbers.. The base is simply how we choose to represent them.

Answer (score 1):

Numbers are numbers. 3 * 0b100 will always equal 12, regardless of whether you use a lookup table or bit shifting to multiply them.

Comment: k but since i'm learning, the way i did it was correct? convert one or the other to the same base (in this case base 10) then do simple multiplication?

Comment: It honestly doesn't matter. `3 * 4` is just as valid as `3 * (1 << 2) + 3 * (0 << 1) + 3 * (0 << 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

You would convert them to integers before multiplying, I would hope.

Thus they're all in binary.

Answer (score 0):

convert Base 2 into base 10 number then multiply
For example:

1000 base 2  x  100 base 10

Converting 1000 base2
1000 base 2 = 2x2x2 = 8

so Multiplication result will be

8 base 10  x 100 base 10  =   800 base 10    =  800

Hope problem solved...